# Building Command From Variable Number of Args Passed

Tags: python, json

My method accepts two properties and a `json` list and returns the corresponding value. It works as expected.

Now, I would like to add the functionality to have it return the corresponding value irrespective of it's depth.

For example, now it accepts `parent` and `child` args and returns a value (see below): `return jsonprops[parent][child]`.

Is it possible to make it accept any number of args and return the corresponding value? `return jsonprops[parent][child1][child2]....[childN]`?

I've found an example of passing variable number of `args` to a method (below), but I'm not sure how to construct the `return jsonprops[parent][child]` since it'll have to order the args in `[]`.

The desired solution will return a value for `return jsonprops[parent][child]` as well as `return jsonprops[parent][child1][child2][child3][child4]`

Passing variable number of args to a method:

```
def multipleArgs(*arg):
    print "Called with", len(arg), "arguments:", arg
```

Reading json file:

```
import json

def read_json(parent, child, jsonprops=[])
    return jsonprops[parent][child]

exampleFile = json.loads(open(example.json).read())
childInfo = read_json('parentProps', 'childProp1', exampleFile)
print childInfo
```

Example json

```
{
  "generalInfo": {
    "name": "example",
    "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    "description": "metadata to be an example"
  },
  "parentProps": {
      "childProp1": "hi 1",
      "childProp2": "hi 2",
      "childProp3": {
        "newParent": [
          {
            "parent1": [
              {
                "grandChild1": "GC1",
                "grandChild2": "GC2",
                "grandChild3": "GC3"
              },
              {
                "numberofKids": "5",
                "grandChild4": "GC4",
                "grandChild5": "GC5",
                "grandChild6": "GC6"
              }
            ],
            "parent2": [
              {
                "numberofKids": "1",
                "grandChild11": "GC11",
                "grandChild12": "GC12",
                "grandChild13": "GC13"
              },
              {
                "grandChild14": "GC14",
                "grandChild15": "GC15",
                "grandChild16": "GC16"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a value from an arbitrary depth within a data structure, you probably want to use a loop. Here's one easy way to do it:

```
def get_value(data, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        data = data[key]
    return data
```

You can also use the the implicit loop performed by the `reduce` function (which in Python 3 is part of the `functools` module):

```
from functools import reduce # this line is only needed in Python 3
from operator import getitem

def get_value(*args): # data should be first argument, followed by any number of keys
    return reduce(getitem, args)
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I'm using Python 2.x. I tried your approach, but it errors on `grandChild1`:   `File "./jsonTest.py", line 15, in get_value
    data = data[key]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. Though it works until depth 3 ('parentProps', 'childProps3', 'newParent').

Comment: The key after `newParent` needs to be an integer, since you have a list in your data structure there (note that the the `grandChild` keys and values are separated into two dictionaries). Try `get_value(jsonprops, 'parentProps', 'childProp3', 'newParent', 0, 'grandChild1')` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However it doesn't work with nested lists (check updated json file.

Comment: I can't imagine why a nested list would be a problem as long as you include an integer index for each level. I don't see any update to the JSON data your question, so I can't give any specifics.

Comment: took me a few min to get the formatting in order... please see above.

Comment: Your new example data structure adds two levels, so you need an extra integer key (for the added list level) and another string (for the added dictionary level). To look up `'GC1'`, you'd use `get_value(jsonprops, 'parentProps', 'childProp3', 'newParent', 0, 'parent1', 0, 'grandChild1')`. You should really be able to figure this out yourself by carefully examining each level of the data structure.

Comment: thanks, I had to check it against a couple of scenarios. Does what it supposed to do. Last Q, is there away to figure how many `parents` exist? I need to iterate over all parents (`parent1`, `parent2`, etc)

Comment: It depends a bit on which of the levels before that can have multiple equivalent items. In particular, is the list under `newParents` only ever going to have one dictionary in it? If so, then the number of parents is `len(jsonprops['parentProps]['childprop3']['newParent'][0])`. But if there can be more than one dictionary with `parentX` keys, you'd need to add up their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html) with the [objectpath](http://objectpath.org/tutorial.html) module:

```
In [22]: from objectpath import Tree

In [23]: j = """
    ...: {
    ...:   "generalInfo": {
    ...:   "name": "example",
    ...:   "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    ...:   "description": "metadata to be an example"
    ...:   },
    ...:   "parentProps": {
    ...:     "childProp1": "hi 1",
    ...:     "childProp2": "hi 2",
    ...:     "childProp3": {
    ...:       "newParent": [
    ...:         {
    ...:         "grandChild1": "GC1",
    ...:         "grandChild2": "GC2",
    ...:         "grandChild3": "GC3"
    ...:         },
    ...:         {
    ...:         "grandChild4": "GC4",
    ...:         "grandChild5": "GC5",
    ...:         "grandChild6": "GC6"
    ...:         }
    ...:       ]
    ...:     }
    ...:   }
    ...: }"""

In [24]: j = json.loads(j)

In [25]: next(Tree(j).execute('$..{}..{}'.format('parentProps', 'childProp1')))
Out[25]: 'hi 1'

In [53]: next(Tree(j).execute('$..{}..{}'.format('newParent', 'grandChild5')))
Out[53]: 'GC5'
```

Your function will then load the json and return the result with the help of objectpath (if there)

Comment: I like the approach, unfortunately I do not have `objectpath` module.